# How to remove generated files in Git repo?

Tags: git

I created a git repo and worked a bit on my android projekt, but now I recognize that I added files into the repo which will change each time because they are generated. How can I remove them and be sure that wont be added again.

I have already added them to the .gitignore which locks like this

```
bin/classes/**
gen/**
bin/PDiXUploader.apk
bin/classes.dex
bin/resources.ap_
gen/de/srs/android/pdixuploader/R.java
```

But now I am not certain how to delete it from the repo so that it wont be under version control.

This is my git status log

```
$ git status
# On branch master
# Changes not staged for commit:
#   (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
#   (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
#
#       modified:   bin/PDiXUploader.apk
#       modified:   bin/classes.dex
#       modified:   bin/resources.ap_
#       modified:   gen/de/srs/android/pdixuploader/R.java
#       modified:   res/layout/activity_instance_selection.xml
#       modified:   res/layout/activity_main.xml
#
# Untracked files:
#   (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)
#
#       res/values/dimens.xml
no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")
```

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
git rm <file>
```

Should remove the file from the repo for you.

Answer (score 10):

Since you only want to remove it from the repository, not from your filesystem, you'll want to use:

```
git rm --cached <file>
```

That will remove the file from the index, so it won't be in the next commit, but will leave the file on disk.

Answer (score 3):

`git rm` is the answer if you want the file to go away going forward.

If you want the generated file never to have been in the repo, you'll want to take a look at  [`git filter-branch`](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-filter-branch.html), the first example in particular.